# How we can add background color in EXCEL for printing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, colors

How we can add background color in EXCEL for printing? I create a small image with gray color and add it to `PAGE LAYOUT-Background Image`. When I see the main window of EXCEL everything is fine and all cells are gray but in print page only used cells are gray and other remaining cells are white. How can I set all page background color to a specific color for printing?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As per Microsoft support site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213977, You cannot print a background graphic for a Excel worksheet

Comment: You are right @teylyn, Images from `imgur` do not load in my office PC. Just checked the question from the mobile app and got to see the image. Thanks

Comment: Your approach the problem is incorrect. If you add an image to the `Background` under Page layout - you will never see it in print. Use fill cells to get the desired colour

Comment: There is a work-around if you want to print with background http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1056-excel-print-background.html

Comment: Another workaround is covered here:  [put an image in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665855/printable-background-image-to-excel/68536387#68536387).

Answer (score 1):

What is the print area? What do you see when you switch to View > Page break preview? Are the page breaks where you expect them to be? If not, change the print area (in Normal view, select the cells you want to print and click Page Layout > Print Area > Set Print Area, or in Page break preview drag the blue page borders)

Comment: I guess that the OP is on a wrong path to do `fill cells` if he is going to use `background` image for that